# Set active scene before awake is called on scene being loaded additively

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a loader script that loads a scene additively. The issue that I am having, is that when the new scene loads, it checks to see if it is the main active scene on `Awake`, if it is not then it loads the scene with this script and that scene reloads the one with the `Awake` check thus creating an infinite loop of scene loads.

With this script, when I try to set the main scene it says it hasn't finished loading yet. If I comment out the `if` statement, I get a scene load loop as mentioned above.

So, how/what can I do to set the active scene before the `Awake` is called on the loading scene's gameobject components?

**Note:** `LoadScene()` is triggered from a `UnityEvent`

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Collections;

public class GSLoadComplete : MonoBehaviour {

  public LoadSceneMode mode;

  [Tooltip("Set the scene as the main scene (Only when mode is set to Addictive)")]
  public bool addictiveSetAsMain;

  public UnityEvent onAddictiveLoadCompleted;

  public void LoadScene(string sceneName) {
    if (mode == LoadSceneMode.Additive) {
      StartCoroutine(LoadSceneAddictive(sceneName));
    } else {
      SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName, mode);
    }
  }

  IEnumerator LoadSceneAddictive(string sceneName) {

    AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, mode);
    asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = false;

    // Wait until the asynchronous scene fully loads
    while (!asyncLoad.isDone) {
      if (asyncLoad.progress >= 0.9f) {
        // Commenting this out creates an infinite load loop
        if (addictiveSetAsMain) {
          SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(sceneName));
        }
        asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = true;
      }
      yield return null;
    }

    onAddictiveLoadCompleted.Invoke();
  }

}
```

This is the script that gets loaded on `Awake`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadMain : MonoBehaviour {

  public string scene;

  void Awake() {
    if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != scene) {
      SceneManager.LoadScene(scene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: For clarification, you mean "Additive", right? Also, loading a scene and setting it to active are two different things. Which one are you needing?

Comment: Yes, Additive is what I mean. I need both to happen.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/scenemanager-loadscene-additive-and-set-active.380826/ is an old(er) thread describing this exact issue. There are events you can use to hook into the SceneManagement for checking loading status and completion